# Hadamard Product and Eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvector, hadamard-product

I just found this related question in here [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237061/change-of-eigenvectors-by-hadamard-product).

Given a positive definite matrix $\mathbf{A}$, consider its eigendecomposition $(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{D})$. Consider an arbitrary matrix $\mathbf{B}$,

> Is there any closed-form expression of the eigendecomposition of
>   $\mathbf{A} \circ \mathbf{B}$?

$\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product.

**Edition 29/05/2015**

Since considering an arbitrary matrix $\mathbf{B}$ does not lead to a closed-form expression, let us consider that all elements of $\mathbf{B}$ can be defined such as $[\mathbf{B}]_{m,n}= e^{i\theta_{m,n}}$ where $\theta_{m,n} \in [0, 2\pi]$ for $m = 1, \ldots , M$ $n = 1, \ldots , N$. Of course,  $\mathbf{A}$ has the same dimensions of $\mathbf{B}$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What data are allowed to appear in your "closed-form expression"? Of course we need to know the eigendecomposition of $B$...

Comment: the obvious answer is: no there won't be a nontrivial closed form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There won't be a nontrivial closed form in general. A trivial "closed-form" is mentioned below.

The Hadamard product $A \circ B$ is a principal submatrix of the Kronecker product $A\otimes B$. Thus, let $A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$ and $B=VDV^{-1}$ (I assumed $B$ is diagonalizable and not fully arbitrary as required in the question). Then, we have
\begin{equation*}
   A \circ B = E^*(U\Lambda U^{-1} \otimes V D V^{-1})E = E^*[(U\otimes V)(\Lambda\otimes D)(U\otimes V)^{-1}]E.
\end{equation*}
Thus $A\circ B$ is a compression of the matrix on the right hand side. This is about as far as we get.

Comment: OK, then I assume no further insights can be obtained.

Comment: @mikitov: if $B$ is special, then surely one can say more; e.g., if $B=11^T$ :-) One can say more precise things about rougher quantities such as $\|A\circ B\|$ etc., or singular value inequalities, and so on; but a fine-grained description of the spectrum seems too hard.