# Possible values of eigenvalues of Hadamard product of Hermitian matrices

Tags: reference-request, matrices, eigenvalues

One of the most important (and very well-known) result in the study of the spectrum of Hermitian matrices is Horn's conjecture (or theorem?), which provides a complete answer to the following problem:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices. Determine all the possible values of the eigenvalues of $A+B$, given the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Given this result,
it seems a natural to wonder if there exists (or could possibly exist) such characterizations for other *combinations* Hermitian matrices.

For instance,
if by *combination* we mean the tensor product,
then the answer is trivial:
the eigenvalues of $A\otimes B$ is simply the set of all products of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

However,
if by combination we mean the Hadamard (or Schur) product
$$(A\circ B)_{ij}=A_{ij}B_{ij},$$
the answer is seemingly nontrivial, as with $A+B$.

Letting $\lambda_1(A\circ B),\ldots,\lambda_n(A\circ B)$ denote the eigenvalues of $A\circ B$,
we observe that
$$\lambda_1(A\circ B)+\cdots+\lambda_n(A\circ B)=\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ii}B_{ii},$$
and thus the set of possible eigenvalues of $A\circ B$ lies in a hyperplane $H$ determined by the diagonal entries of $A$ and $B$,
which are themselves (to some extent) determined by the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

My question is thus the following:

> Does there exist conjectures or results on what the set of possible eigenvalues of $A\circ B$ might look like in the hyperplane
>   $$x_1+\cdots+x_n=\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ii}B_{ii},$$
>   or is there a reason to believe that there is little hope to find a satisfying description of such a subset?

Comment: This question is very close to: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207836/hadamard-product-and-eigendecomposition/207840#207840

Comment: ... (in particular, since $A \circ B$ is a principal submatrix of $A\otimes B$, the eigenvalues it can assume are going to satisfy the usual interlacing inequalities. Since $\lambda(A\otimes B) = \lambda_i(A)\lambda_j(B)$, this gives us a reasonable characterization. Are you looking for something more detailed?)

Comment: Restricting $A, B$ to positive semidefinite matrices.  THEOREM 3 in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379585901478# may be a nice relation you are looking for.